# Выполнение функции в определенный момент времени

Tags: python, flask

Недавно начал изучать Python Flask, и появился вопрос, на который бы хотелось получить совет.
Предположим мой проект развернут на raspberry, и дома через веб-страничку я могу включать/выключать реле, считывать температуру, влажность и тд. Но теперь я хочу чтобы функция, отвечающая за вкл/выкл реле, срабатывала не по нажатию кнопки, а автоматически в определенный момент времени, например в 12-45 и в 19:01.
В свое время без проблем делал похожее на C#, но что-то похожее на flask'e найти не получилось.
Возможно ли вообще реализовать это? 
Буду благодарен за любой совет, ссылку.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214270/scheduling-a-function-to-run-every-hour-on-flask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам может помочь модуль [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/).
С его помощью можно легко планировать какие-либо действия.

***Пример (из документации):***

```py
import schedule
import time


def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Также, могу предложить Вам [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

***Пример:***

```py
from threading import Timer


def job():
    print("I'm working...")

t = Timer(86400, job)
t.start()
```

Этот вариант запускается в отдельном потоке, поэтому не мешает выполнению остального  кода.
При желании можно написать класс-обёртку и перезапускать его по нужному условию.